# Business Validation Error: Amount must be zero for bundle line items.Error in quickbooks accounting api using coldfusion

Tags: java, api, coldfusion, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying from 2 days to solve this issue but no success till now.I am working on intuit quickbooks api using coldfusion and java at the backend. I am generating invoice but facing a strange error that says that

ERROR CODE:6000, ERROR MESSAGE:A business validation error has occurred while processing your request, ERROR DETAIL:Business Validation Error: Amount must be zero for bundle line items.

It is the chunk of my code

```
<cfset Line.setLineNum(bigInt)>

<cfset Line.setDescription('#qOrderDetails.PARENT_SKU_DESC[sk]#')>

<cfif sk eq 1>
     <cfset amount = JavaCast('bigdecimal', #tPrice#)>
</cfif>

<cfset amount = JavaCast('bigdecimal', #tPrice#)> 
<cfset Line.setAmount(amount)>

<cfset Line.setDetailType(createObject("java", 'com.intuit.ipp.data.LineDetailTypeEnum').SALES_ITEM_LINE_DETAIL)>

<cfset SalesItemLineDetail = createObject("java", 'com.intuit.ipp.data.SalesItemLineDetail')>

<cfset ItemReferenceType = createObject("java", 'com.intuit.ipp.data.ReferenceType')>

<cfset ItemReferenceType.setValue("1031")>
```

I am providing 0 amount in the function and even i have tried to put hardcoded 0 in the function but still the same error.